# Why does TypeScript not support export @deco?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

This problem was discussed in https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/issues/69, so why doesn't TypeScript support it?

This code doesn't work:

```
export @deco()
class a {};
```

While this one does:

```
@deco
export class a {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [issue #31370](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31370):

> The [Decorators Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) is still in flux and we do not intend to make any significant changes to our implementation until the proposal has officially reached Stage 3. We will revisit this issue at that time.

The Decorators Proposal is currently at stage 2, by the way.